# Object comparison: Address vs Content

Tags: java

Hey guys im just messing around and I cant get this to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String x = "hey";
    System.out.println("What is x?:  ");
    x = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);
    if (x == "hello")
        System.out.println("hello");
    else
        System.out.println("goodbye");
}
```

it is of course supposed to print hello hello if you enter hello but it will not.  I am using Eclipse just to mess around.  A little quick help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be `if (x.equals("hello"))`.

With java objects, `==` is used for reference comparison. `.equals()` for value comparison.

Comment: This is weird I have never had to do this with scanner. Is this an Eclipse specific? probably dumb question...

Comment: This isn't "weird", it is the way things are done in Java. It has nothing to do with Eclipse ;)

Comment: or null-safe: `"hello".equals(x)`

Comment: no, this is the behavior of java, the references of the strings is not equal although their content is the same.

Comment: thanks man. is there another way to do if statements with scanner? I really never remember doing this

Comment: This is not about `scanner` or if statements, it is regarding object comparison in Java in general.

Comment: Oh i guess I have been using another type like char or int which would be correct. ok sorry for the inconvenience thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `==` when testing for equality of non basic types, it will test **for reference equality**. Use `.equals(..)` instead.

Look at the following diagram:

[image: equals vs ==]

When using `==` you're comparing the addresses of the boxes, when using `equals` you're comparing their content.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a string like that.Because String is a class.So if you want to compare its content use equals

```
 if (x.equals("hello"))
        System.out.println("hello");
    else
        System.out.println("goodbye");
```

Answer (score 1):

x=="hello" compares the references not values , you will have to do x.equals("hello").

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
    if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
    if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT
    if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
    if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // CORRECT>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"hello".equals(x)` and **never** reverse since it **does not** handle null.

Answer (score 1):

== operator checks equality of references (not values). In your case you have 2 String type object which have different reference but same value "hello". String class has "equals" method for checking values equality. The syntax is if(str1.equals(str2)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the comparison:

```
if (x.equals("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use x.equals("hello");

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Take this sample program:

```
public class StringComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "hello";
        System.out.println(hello == "hello");

        String hello2 = "hel" + "lo";
        System.out.println(hello == hello2);

        String hello3 = new String(hello);
        System.out.println(hello == hello3);
        System.out.println(hello3.equals(hello));
    }
}
```

Its output would be:

```
true
true
false
true
```

Objects `hello` and `hello3` have different references that's why `hello == hello3` is false, but they contain the same string, therefore `equals` returns true.

The expression `hello == hello2` is true because Java compiler is smart enough to perform concatenation of two string constants.

*So to compare String objects, you have to use `equals` method.*